# как переименовать домен в opensrver?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, openserver

Есть  домен в openserver. Как его переименовать, чтобы сайт после моих действий начал работать?

Comment: Запусти командную строку и выполни команду `shutdown -r -t 0`; Следующая команда `connect :\ yoururl:\ login\ password`
Следующая команда `set new domain :\domainname`

Comment: Для изменения домена в OpenServer надо войти в настройки сервера, и в списке Домены выбрать нужный домен. Изменив его имя, сохранить настройки - сервер перезапустится самостоятельно.

Comment: @Victor это уже можно было публиковать как ответ )

Comment: @DanielProtopopov и ваш комментарий тоже на ответ похож. )

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения домена в OpenServer надо войти в настройки сервера, и в списке Домены выбрать нужный домен.

[image: Первый шаг]

Изменив его имя ...

[image: Второй шаг]

... сохранить настройки - сервер перезапустится самостоятельно.

[image: Третий шаг]